# Unable to receive data from firebase database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to display data from a Firebase database in Dialogflow responses.

This is my code:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function getArtikel (agent) {

    return db.collection('artikel').get()
        .then(doc => {
                db.collection('artikel').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                        return agent.add(doc.data());
                    });
                });
            return Promise.resolve('Search finished');
        }).catch(() => {
            agent.add('Error');
        });
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('GetArtikel', getArtikel);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Unfortunately, the agent only returns a empty response but the log contains the data as expected. What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an empty response because `db.collection('artikel').get()` returns a `promise`. It means **it runs asynchronously**. If you logged on Chrome, you can see the result after expanding the array (look at the [i] icon)

You can simply fix the problem by adding `async` to your function and `await` after return:

```
async function getArtikel (agent)
return await db.collection('artikel').get()
```

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg&t=231s) for more information on `async/await`

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot :)